# Visual PHPUnit File path not found error

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I am trying to use Visual PHPUnit https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit/
My OS is OSX version 10.8.5.

I installed pear .It works well. I checked following the http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php#installation.checking.cli.phpdir

I installed phpunit via pear.

When I run I got the error

```
( ! ) Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/myname/Sites/VisualPHPUnit/app/config/bootstrap.php on line 83


( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/share/pear:/Users/myname/pear/share/pear:/usr/local/pear/share/pear:/Users/myname/Sites/VisualPHPUnit:/usr/local/pear/share') in /Users/myname/Sites/VisualPHPUnit/app/config/bootstrap.php on line 83
```

So is PHPUnit folder supposed to be under pear path or in my project path?
And is my phpunit installation problem?Any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

To see where pear installed phpunit do

```
$ pear list phpunit/phpunit
```

Comment: When I check , my phpunit is  
C:\Users\seintsan>pear list phpunit/phpunit
INSTALLED FILES FOR PHPUNIT/PHPUNIT
===================================
TYPE   INSTALL PATH
doc    C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\docs\PHPUnit\LICENSE
doc    C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\docs\PHPUnit\README.md
script C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\phpunit
script C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\phpunit.bat . there is no Autoload.php file under the directory.